# Portable application not showing in win32com browser, how to dispatch it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-10, python-3.6, win32com

There is a portable software which communicates with a scientific instrument. It is a portable software, where one can just copy the whole folder to anywhere in any PC.

And by double clicking the '.exe' file, one can start to talk to the instrument using this software. It has a ProgID like "portable.application", but it is not shown in the com browser.

When I do

```
 win32com.client.Dispatch("portable.application")
```

The error is

```
com_error: (-2147221005, 'Invalid class string', None, None)
```

How can I dispatch this application? I guess I need to register the application to the registry somehow.

Comment: Problem solved, I was just dumb.

Answer (score 2):

One way to check the attributes in a COM object is using the `combrowse.py` available on `win32com\client` in your python site-packages folder

[image]

If the `portable.application` you're looking for isn't listed, you can't access that application.

Take a look at the following link that might help..

http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/html/com/win32com/HTML/QuickStartClientCom.html